# When deleting connecting from sql server all connections are deleted not just the one i want

Tags: vb.net, database-connection

In vb,net i have some code to remove selected user connections from a sql server database.

At present when i open the page it deletes all user connections, this should not happen. I should open the page and click the delete button on the table row then it removes the connection.

I'm working in Visual Studio with vb.net

Please see my code and offer advice

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim dtTable As DataTable = Nothing
        Dim intConnectionId As Integer = 0

        If IsPostBack Then

            intConnectionId = CInt(result.Value)

            ' Get user data from session
            With HttpContext.Current

            End With

        End If

        Using sqlCommand As New SqlCommand
            With sqlCommand
                .CommandText = "usp_connectsdetailedlist"
                .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

                ' Remove connection
                modConnections.Delete(intConnectionId)

                ' Clear desks attahced to connection
                modDeskText.ClearUserDesk(intConnectionId)

                ' Send message to server to delete connection
                modMessages.Send(ccsStdCallBackCon.scbcDisconnect, intConnectionId, True)

            End With

            Execute(sqlCommand, dtTable)
        End Using

        With Rep1
            .DataSource = dtTable.DefaultView
            .DataBind()
        End With

        If Not IsNothing(dtTable) Then
            dtTable.Dispose()
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: The issue is likely not in the code you've provided but in the code that actually does the deleting.

Comment: As you can see, code in comments is pretty much unreadable.  Edit your question and add relevant code there.

Answer (score 0):

1. The problem is you written delete connection code in page_Load, so
   it is executing whenever the page loads.
2. Try to add a button and write the same code in Button_Click event.

Comment: ah i see thanks, is there not a way for me to make it so it only runs the sql commands on postback?

Comment: I also realized that im passing a 0 through for intConnectionId so have removed that, as that was selecting all users.

Comment: if you want to make it only run for post backs, just move you delete code into  " If IsPostBack Then----End If "

Comment: yep just did that and looking a lot better now, i just need to put a final check in there to check my var(intConnectionId) isnt = to 0. Thank you Munna +1 for pointing me in the right direction.